# how to Recovery RAID 5 storage that deleted array by console

Tags: raid5

I have A IBM DS3400 Storage this storage deleted  array by console command. My Question is how to Recover data From this storage.

thank all.

Answer (score 5):

Call your vendor ***now***.  They're the best people to help you.

Assuming you have support, that is.

And if you don't.. Why don't you?

Comment: If you don't have support: Pull out your backups. Assuming you have backups, that is. And if you don't.. Why don't you?  (Sorry, Tom)....

Comment: we emailed to  IBM For This but no response from IBM

Comment: Give them time, they're a huge multinational.